# SE Theoretical CS Pizza Ambassador Program: Sponsored discussion groups

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Stack Exchange is looking for students and teachers interested in a new pizza ambassador program. Stack Exchange would like to sponsor university students (and external academic/study groups) who are excited about Theoretical CS, intellectual discussion, and free food. Selected students are enabled to organize get-togethers around discussions of Theoretical CS, sponsored by Stack Exchange. Write *academics@stackexchange.com* for more information and to get involved.

Updated: Valid anywhere.

Comment: Another great idea. I just forwarded this note to my students :)

Comment: Is this only valid in the states?

Comment: For those who wondered, I received an answer, the program can be down outside the USA.

Comment: What kind of get-together are you aiming at? Informal meetings, question-answering sprints, workshops or cooperations? Everything?

Comment: @Raphael Everything reasonable- it varies based on people's preferred learning and discussion style. Some people tend to chat about papers etc. over lunch, while others may prefer a Q&A in a classroom.

Comment: Just sent an email to the posted address.